# readonly property utilizando lambda

Tags: c#

se me pidió explicar el siguiente código en C#

```
public class Persona 
{
public string Nombre{get;}="Pedro";
public string Apellido=>"Paco";
}
```

mi respuesta fue que en el caso de la propiedad Nombre es una propiedad de solo lectura y que se le asigna el valor inicial de Pedro.
para la propiedad Apellido le especifique que también es de solo lectura y que le asigno mediante lambda el valor de Paco.
mi sorpresa fué que me indicó que la segunda respuesta es incorrecta y he buscado y estoy seguro que estoy bien aunque obviamente me he equivocado, podrían indicarme la respuesta correcta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Habria que ver que version de C# esta considerando para la respuesta

[Expression-bodied members (C# programming guide)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members)

si es la version `C# 6` entonces tienes razon, alli dice:

> with C# 6, you can use expression body definition to implement a read-only property

Igualmente si querias que sea una `propiedad` que ademas use `lambda` quizas quede mas explicito si usas

```
public class Persona 
{
   public string Nombre{get;}="Pedro";
   public string Apellido {
       get => "Paco";
   }              
}
```